# Unable to pull hyperledger/cello-api-engine image

Tags: hyperledger-cello

Setup of Hyperledger-cello:

1. Cloned Hyperledger-cello 0.9.0
2. sudo SERVER_PUBLIC_IP=xx.xx.xx.xx make start

I am facing the following issue:

> ERROR: pull access denied for hyperledger/cello-api-engine, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
>
> Makefile:211: recipe for target 'start-docker-compose' failed

I tried changing name of image in docker-compose.yml file, but stuck with the same issue.

> ERROR: The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.
>
> Continue with the new image? [yN]n
> ERROR: pull access denied for hyperledger/cello-api-engine, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
> Makefile:211: recipe for target 'start-docker-compose' failed
> make[1]: *** [start-docker-compose] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

Hey the problem is that on master is not the most stable release, so, in orderer it to work they have changed a little bit. After cloning you need to do the following.

```
make docker
```

This will build all the images, on the documentation they say that for now this is mandatory.

And after that is finished do the following:

```
make start
```

This will start the network.

If you are looking for a more stable build you can checkout to the tag 0.9.0.

Take on account that this project is still on incubator and they are preparing for the 1.0.0 release, on the master branch you may see that there is missing documentation and more.

Comment: After completion of  make steps , it will work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no cello-api-engine in docker hub. 
You can check list here
[cello docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=hyperledger%2Fcello&type=image)

If you change from cello-api-engine to cello-engine, that error will not appear. But there is also no cello-dashboard in docker hub images for next step. there are only cello-operator-dashboard and cello-user-dashboard.

Comment: I changed the images names in dockercompose.yaml file with existing image names,coming up,but containers are not running.They are restarting within seconds.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change any image name in .yaml files,after running setp-master, it is going to create images in your mahcine . Done with images part.
If anyone face issue let me knwow :)